# Node Joi: Value of a joi key must match with one object key in a joi array

Tags: node.js, validation, schema, joi

This is my Joi schema

```
const createRoom = {
  body: {
    createdBy: Joi.string().required(),
    members: Joi.array().min(2).max(2).items(
      Joi.object().keys({
        id: Joi.string().required(),
        name: Joi.string().required(),
      })
    ).unique('id').required()
  }
}
```

What i want is

> The value of `createdBy` must match with one unique object id in members array

### Example

**This input should pass**

```
{
  createdBy: 'abcd1234',
  members: [
    {
      id: 'abcd1234',
      name: "john"
    },
    {
      id: 'xyz1234',
      name: "john"
    }
  ]
}
```

**This input should fail**

```
{
  createdBy: 'abcd1234',
  members: [
    {
      id: 'bcdf1234',
      name: "john"
    },
    {
      id: 'xyz1234',
      name: "john"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this possible with joi? I didn't find anything like this in [Joi Docs](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0).

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [array.has](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#arrayhasschema) with [ref](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#refkey-options):

```
const schema = Joi.object({
 createdBy: Joi.string().required(),
 members: Joi.array().min(2).max(2).items(
    Joi.object().keys({
        id: Joi.string().required(),
        name: Joi.string().required(),
    }))
    .has(Joi.object({ 
        id: Joi.string().required().valid(Joi.ref('$createdBy')),
        name: Joi.string()
    }))
    .unique('id')
})
```

With array.has you are saying that you want at least one of those objects inside the array. And Joi.ref lets access you any value of the current object.

This means that the following object will pass:

```
const validObj = {
  createdBy: 'abcd1234',
  members: [
    {
      id: 'abcd1234',
      name: "john"
    },
    {
      id: 'xyz1234',
      name: "john"
    }
  ]
}

schema.validate(validObj, { context: validObj })
```

And this will fail:

```
const invalidObj = {
  createdBy: 'abcd1234',
  members: [
    {
      id: 'xxxx',
      name: "john"
    },
    {
      id: 'xyz1234',
      name: "john"
    }
  ]
}

schema.validate(invalidObj, { context: invalidObj })
```

This will also fail since there is a duplicate:

```
const invalidObj = {
  createdBy: 'abcd1234',
  members: [
    {
      id: 'abcd1234',
      name: "john"
    },
    {
      id: 'abcd1234',
      name: "john"
    }
  ]
}

schema.validate(invalidObj, { context: invalidObj })
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, @soltex my usecase is a little different. As you mentioned the part `.has(Joi.object({  id: Joi.string().required().valid(Joi.ref('$createdBy')),  name: Joi.string() }))`, i only want to validate id. I tried with that but it never passed the validation.

Comment: I will updated the question with what i tried.

Comment: @Huzaifa what do you mean? The examples you provided are working with my schema. Please update your question with an example that is not working.